# If header is equal to a specific value in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with Codes and dates as headers and numbers as values. I want to see sum of each row based on a certain date ("Date" is the last header); before that date and after the date using python.
I have calculated the first row using color to show what I want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmrG7.png)

Comment: please don't use images of data, provide a [reproducible input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464)

Comment: Sure, I will. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two columns Before/After are not pre-existing (if they are, you can `drop` them), you can reshape, then `groupby.sum` and `merge`:

```
tmp = (df.melt(['Code', 'Date'])
   .astype({'Date': str, 'variable': 'str'})
   .assign(col=lambda d: np.where(d['Date'].gt(d['variable']),
                                  'Before', 'After'))
   .groupby(['Code', 'col'])['value'].sum()
   .unstack('col')[['Before', 'After']]
)

out = df.merge(tmp, left_on='Code', right_index=True, how='left')
```

Output:

```
    Code  202001  202002  202003  202004  202005  202006  202007  202008  202009  202010  202011  202012    Date  Before  After
0  12345    1000    1001    1002    1003    1004    1005    3006    1007    1008    1009    1010    1011  202004    3003  11063
1  12346     999    1000    1001    1002    1003    1003    1005    1006    1007    1008    1009    1010  202006    5005   7048
2  12347    1983    1984    1985    1986    1987    1988    1989    1990    1991    1992    1993    1994  202010   17883   5979
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how large your input is, you can just do something like this. I admit that this is somewhat of a lazy looping solution, so its performance will likely depend on the dimensions of your real-life DF.

```py
import pandas as pd


def summify_b(input: dict) -> int:
    check_date = input.pop("Date")
    rtn_val = 0

    for k in input:
        if k < check_date and k not in ["Before", "After"]:
            rtn_val += input[k]

    return rtn_val


def summify_a(input: dict) -> int:
    check_date = input.pop("Date")
    rtn_val = 0

    for k in input:
        if k >= check_date and k not in ["Before", "After"]:
            rtn_val += input[k]

    return rtn_val


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "202001": [1000, 999, 1983],
        "202002": [1001, 1000, 1984],
        "202003": [1002, 1001, 1002],
        "202004": [1003, 1002, 1003],
        "Date": ["202001", "202002", "202003"],
    }
)

df["Before"] = df.apply(lambda x: summify_b(dict(x)), axis=1)
df["After"] = df.apply(lambda x: summify_a(dict(x)), axis=1)

print(df)
```

output:

```
   202001  202002  202003  202004    Date  Before  After
0    1000    1001    1002    1003  202001       0   4006
1     999    1000    1001    1002  202002     999   3003
2    1983    1984    1002    1003  202003    3967   2005
```